# Librería datepicker de bootstrap en mozilla firefox no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datetimepicker

Tengo un campo fecha

```
<div class='input-group date' >
 <input name="date_ven" type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".date").datetimepicker({
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        view: 'years',
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
});
</script>
```

Funciona bien en Chrome, pero no despliega en Firefox.

Este es el error me aparece en consola de firefox

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: (intermediate value).toString(...).split(...)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A mí hay veces que se me vuelve loco, y necesito poner la clase en el input, en lugar de ponerlo en el div

. Prueba con este código

```
<div class='input-group' >
    <input name="date_ven" type='text' class="form-control date" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $(".date").datetimepicker({
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        view: 'years',
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
     });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te envío el código como lo tengo implementado y no me falla en ningún navegador
(No uso el boton para desplegar el datetimepicker, sino que al hacer foco en el input se despliega automaticamente)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    locale: 'es'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
</div>
```

Ojo: para que te funcione el locale: 'es', para colocar el calendario en español
debes descargar o referenciar el pluging es.js de moment

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/es.js"></script>
```

Comment: No me funciono en mozilla firefox pero en crome si, me regalan las librerías que utilizan  llevo bastante tiempo y no he podido solucionar algo he buscado y parece un problema de librerias Gracias...